# Connection node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, phpmyadmin

I am having trouble connecting **node js** with my database in **phpmyadmin**, I do not understand where this problem is coming from:

the code:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    database : 'db_client3',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error connecting: ' + err.stack);
        return;
    } 
    console.log('Connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
});

connection.end();
```

However when I execute the code with the terminal, I get this error.

Command line:

> node app.js

```
Error connecting: Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "nodejs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "node js test ",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: So, I assume you removed the root password for that database, and you do not have the same issue when you connect with a mysql client. Is that right?

Comment: Can you please update your post with your `package.json` file content?

Comment: Yes I have just update it

Comment: Try to connect using **mySql Client** to make sure you have the right credentials ...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding port like this,

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    database : 'db_client3',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    port : '3000'
});
```

***Note*** : Make sure that you are not running anything on the given **port**

If it doesn't work change your **mysql** version to **latest** in package.json.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mysql = require("mysql")

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host:"localhost",
    user:"root",
    password:"",
    database:"db_client3",
    port : '3000'

})

    con.connect((error)=>{
        if(!error){
            console.log("connected with database...")
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Error While Connecting With Database...",error)
        }
    })
```

try something like this

if issue not solve with above solution then
**please check you database password and make it *null* and if issue is still not solve then i suggest you to Create new user instead of using root**